# Core Data. Fastest way to fill 2 double linked entities?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I have 2 tables (and similar entities):

1. Category (has string property identifier)
2. CategoryLink (has properties category1 and category2 which are pointers to Category objects)

And I have a text file with info about categories and their links. The info about links is represented as pairs of first and second link id.

I want to fill my database using Core Data. I fill Category enough fast but I have troubles with performance with CategoryLink.

My best implementation is:

1. get all the categories sorted by identifier;
2. get the whole link info from file to an array of dictionaries, sorted by first item id;
3. a cycle for-each for each category from (1)
4. in cycle (3) I search for a second category using ID from (2) in iteration and create an object of CategoryLink entity.

The performance is too slow because there are a lot of Categories and CategoryLinks records should be inserted. So are there ways to improve the performance?

Comment: Which part is taking to long? Also, are there duplicates (like AB and BA)?

Comment: Category and CategoryLink records are both unique. It is hard to say which part takes a the most part of time because because the code is inside a block. But I think the longest task is to search the second category at least as much times as the count of CategoryLink entity objects

Comment: You can time also inside a block. Do a `NSTimeInterval x = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];` on both sides and log the difference.

Comment: Ok. I checked and it is still searching for a second category even without other actions from (4). But it looks enough fast (~0.036 of a second).
P.S. You don't need to use special timers except of situations when you want to perform some special calculations such as interval. In most cases it is enough to log something (it writes log time also).

Comment: For performance issues, run the app under Instruments. You'll get a much clearer picture of **exactly** where your app is spending time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are doing all the lookups in memory, the most important performance factor is how often you save your context.

Don't save in each iteration of your loop. Try to save in batches. The ideal number depends on the data but it is often around 500-2000.

For starters, try to save only at the end and see how long that takes.

I would iterate thorough your sorted list of dictionaries and always keep a reference to catgory1.

Comment: can you say a little bit more about it. I have 2 threads while db is filling. The first thread is main and the second is created by me to fill the database separatelly from screen drawing/updating.
As you can see the code desribed before doesn't contain [context save:...]. The app is too slow on entity objects' creating and filling only.